# How to prevent CostFinalize action from deleting folder/files during UNINSTALL

Tags: wix

Below is the log between CostFinalize start and end. I was to retain MyFolder folder and its contents. But it get deleted as default action

Action start 9:30:32: CostFinalize.

Adding ABCDIR property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\ABC\MyFolder\'.
PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying .....this is does for all the elements in Myfolder

MSI (s) (98:F8) [09:30:32:860]: Dir (target): Key: ABCDIR , Object: C:\ProgramData\ABC\MyFolder\

Action ended 9:30:35: CostFinalize. Return value 1.

Comment: Please explain what you need to do in detail. You want to install a folder that is preserved on updates? This is easiest done by generating the folder with your application and populating it with files instantiated from read-only copies installed elsewhere.

Comment: Myfolder gets created during install. While uninstalling the app, I want to retain MyFolder.

Comment: Are you live with your product? If not just use that approach I described and don't install this folder at all - then it is de-coupled from deployment concerns for good. If you are live, then cleanup can be hard and usually involves using a minor upgrade to patch the existing installation with changes to allow uninstall to happen without the problem. A minor upgrade does not run uninstall, and hence it can "hotfix" the uninstall sequence before it is invoked later. Let's hope you are not live yet.

Comment: Not live. The folder should be present after install and  if I pass a command line option only then (un)-installer should exclude the folder from deleting. But my observation that CostFinalize deletes it and its content.

Comment: I have added an answer below, but it is a little involved to explain these sequence things in MSI. Have a look and see if it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

***Costing***: [**`CostFinalize`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/costfinalize-action) is the standard action that is part of "costing" - the overall process of determining disk space installation requirements and other things. [**`File Costing`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/file-costing) is a central part of this process. There are other things happening too - such as resolving directories and scheduling files for I/o operations I guess - not sure of all the details to be honest - they aren't really documented fully.

The costing actions do not make any changes to the system as far as I know, but they will help **schedule** files to be installed or uninstalled. Hence it might look like the deletion happened because of this action.

***RemoveFiles***: The **`InstallExecuteSequence`** is processed twice. First to build an execution script and then to run the actual installation transaction operations. During this second run the standard actions **`RemoveFiles`** and **`InstallFiles`** do the respective file operations and your files will likely be removed by the **`RemoveFiles`** action - unless there is a custom action doing the deletion somewhere else in the sequence.